# Why is ToLookup() dependent on load options in Linq2Sql?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, lookup, eager-loading

Lets say I have 3 tables Posts, PostTags and Tags defining a many-to-many relationship. I want to get a lookup table that will give me all the Posts related to a given tag so I use the following code:

```
return dataContext.PostTags.ToLookup(pt => pt.Tag, pt => pt.Post);
```

In unit test all went fine but in the real application, it didn't work. I found out that I had different load options between my unit test and my application.

When `dataContext.DeferredLoadingEnabled = true;`, everything is fine and works as expected but when `dataContext.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;` and you don't have the load options from `PostTags` to `Post` and `Tag`, the lookup returned contains a single key (null) with an empty array for value. The generated SQL is

```
SELECT [t0].[PostID], [t0].[TagID]
FROM [dbo].[PostTags] AS [t0]
```

So when it generates the lookup, `pt => pt.Post` returns `null` and the same goes for Tags.

Why can't the Linq2SQL provider generate the right SQL in that case?

**Clarification**: By the right SQL, any SQL that would return the right Post and Tag objects and allow for grouping them correctly.

Comment: Generally I stay away from LoadOptions and stick to deferred loading. Easy enough to generate relatively fast SQL if needed from that point of view.

Comment: Now that we have used loadoptions in our application, I feel the same way you do about them. Unfortunately, it is too late to change the way the entire application works. In the next project, you can be certain I will convince my colleagues of the benefits of deferred loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it work no matter what the DeferredLoadingEnabled property value is and whatever the loadoptions are:

```
var lookup = (from pt in dataContext.PostTags
              select new {pt.Post, pt.Tag}).ToLookup(x => x.Tag, x => x.Post);
```

Comment: Microsoft's team seems to think this is the desired behaviour: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/netfxbcl/thread/b3c13f39-6173-4348-9036-76e8a57a6f4a Accepted my own answer with workaround.